# ¿Cómo obtener el response de un array de PHP en Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, array

Cual es la sintaxis correcta para obtener un array multidimensional enviado desde php en formato JSON a Ajax?

Yo lo hago de esta manera:

```
success: function(response) {

alert(response.Monto[0]));
```

Y funciona correctamente siempre y cuando el array que mando es simple:

```
$MontoTotal['Monto'] = [$Monto];
echo json_encode($MontoTotal);
```

Pero si mando un array multidimensional no funciona:

```
$montos = array($Monto[$i]);

$MontoTotal['Monto'] = $montos;
echo json_encode($MontoTotal);
```

Y en javascript para poder acceder en vez de poner el

```
success: function(response) {
```

Tengo que cambiar a:

```
complete: function(response) {
```

para poder por lo menos hacer un alert dentro.

El response con F12 en el navegador si aparece correctamente en ambos casos, pero al momento de querer tomarlo de la misma manera:

```
response.Monto[0]) //marca que 0 es indefinido
```

Dejo aqui el response:[Response](http://avantaxconsultores.com/Calculadoras/Captura.PNG)

Comment: No me queda claro que formato tiene `$MontoTotal`. ¿Podrías agregar en la pregunta un ejemplo del JSON enviado en cada caso con `echo json_encode($MontoTotal);`?. Otra cosa, no parece ser necesario (según http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ cambiar `success:` por `complete:` ¿por qué tuviste que cambiarlo?

Comment: Tuve que cambiarlo porque no funcionaba, 

Esto es lo que esta en el php

$montos = array($Saldo[$i],$Recargos[$i],$Principal[$i],$Importe[$i],$Saldo[$i]);
$MontoTotal['Monto'] = $montos; echo json_encode($MontoTotal);

Comment: como imprimes tu json. osea que datos imprimes en tu archivo json.

Comment: No hay duda de que la función para obtener los resultados es `success` (y no `complete`)

Comment: @Emilio Platzer: Que mal, porque success no funciona,
@AnimationsNow: En php a ajax mando por json lo siguiente:
`$montos = array($Monto[$i]); $MontoTotal['Monto'] = $montos;
echo json_encode($MontoTotal);`
En el ajax lo unico que deperdido quiero hacer es un alert:
alert(response.Monto[0])); , este alert funciona siempre y cuando en el json que mando no mande un array dentro.

Comment: Entiendo, pero usas un for o foreach para generar tu json o sólo lo haces así como en el codigo que muestras.

Comment: Me encuentro dentro de un for para poder recorrer el array de $Monto cada vez que $i incremente

Answer (score 1):

Cuando trabajo con php y arrays bidimensionales lo hago de esta forma:

PHP

```
$data["clientes"] = ["datos"=> [
        "asd1"=>["nombre"=>"Alfonso","paterno"=>"Carrasco"], 
        "asd2"=>["nombre"=>"Ramon","paterno"=>"Perez"],
        "asd3"=>["nombre"=>"alejandra","paterno"=>"ramirez"], 
        "asd1"=>["nombre"=>"pamela","paterno"=>"anderson"]]];

print_r(json_encode($data));
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
success: función(d) {
    var a = JSON.parse(d);
    var clientes=a.clientes;
    var datos = clientes.datos;
    for(var b in datos){
        var x = datos[b];
        console.log("id cliente: "+x,"nombre"+x.nombre,"paterno: "+x.paterno);
    }
}
```

---

Ahora que ya tiene el json prueba con esto.

Javascript

```
for(var a in response)//iteramos en el array
{
    var b = response[a];
    //Acá en el console agregas todos los apuntadores del array
    console.log(b.Monto, b.Monto[0],b.Monto[1]);
    var y = b.Monto; // Pasamos todas las variables que contiene Monto a la variable y
    for(var z in y){  /Iteamos toda la y 
    var zy = y[z]; //Accesamos a indices de iterador
    console.log(zy); Imprimimos todo lo que contenga tus datos de Monto
}
```

Comment: Hola que tal, intente lo que me dijiste pero sigue sin funcionar dejo aquí el response que me da el navegador, el detalle como comento es la sintaxis correcta para tomar los valores en el ajax

( http://avantaxconsultores.com/Calculadoras/Captura.PNG )

Comment: Listo ahí ya lo tienes ahora sólo a iterar...  haber postes tu código de javascript y vemos que onda...

Comment: Eso siempre lo eh tenido, lo que no se es cual es la sintaxis para recogerlo en el ajax despues del complete/success :
response.Monto[0]; no funciona ni el ejemplo que mandaste

Comment: @alfonso `función` no creo que te lo acepte el parser debería ser `function`, también parece que tienes una linea repetida en el arreglo `PHP`.